# Linked images inside SVG

Tags: html, svg

Imagine the following SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <image xlink:href="foo.png" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"/>
</svg>
```

The image, foo.png, resides in the same directory. If we open this SVG in the browser, it will display foo.png correctly. But if we try to use this SVG in `<img src="...">`, or in `<image xlink:href="..."/>` inside another SVG, there will be no foo.png displayed. Tested with latest Firefox and Chrome, both with file:// and http://. There is nothing in the console of either browser, and network monitor shows no attempts to load a bitmap.

Am I missing something? I know everything will be OK if I embed foo.png as "data:image/svg+xml;base64,...", but I really want to avoid that. Bitmaps I'm trying to include can be rather huge, so I would better prefer linking instead of embedding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can an SVG included in HTML with an "img" tag have a link to an external image with the "image" tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352985/can-an-svg-included-in-html-with-an-img-tag-have-a-link-to-an-external-image-w)

Comment: you can use `<object data="image.svg" type="image/svg+xml"/>` instead

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is disabled by the browser for security reasons.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_as_an_Image),

> Restrictions
>
> For security purposes, Gecko places some restrictions on SVG content
>   when it's being used as an image:
>
> - JavaScript is disabled.
> - **External resources (e.g. images, stylesheets) cannot be loaded, though they can be used if inlined through BlobBuilder object URLs or
>     data: URIs.**
> - :visited-link styles aren't rendered.
> - Platform-native widget styling (based on OS theme) is disabled.

Also, check the details at [Bugzilla@Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=628747)