# SVG image as background in css and gradients attached in png jpg

Tags: css, svg, background

Hello illustrator export vector to svn and created attachments with gradients in jpg and png files. How to attach this files to see gradients. I use it as a background in css like this:

```
   background:url(gfx/logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat; background-image:url(gfx/logo.svg),none;
```

(it means that if browser not support svg then show png)

any ideas ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linked images inside SVG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655736/linked-images-inside-svg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create your svg in Adobe Illustrator, there are `Options` for `Image Location` while saving: `Embed` or `Link`. Selecting `Embed` might help with complex vectors with gradients and filters applied, whose would be saved as a single file, and you will be able to use it as a background.

Comment: Now works great but to be sure better use svg optimizer from this site http://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-optimiser  :)