# Include svg in another php generated svg

Tags: php, image, svg

I am using php to return an svg image based on availability of devices in my network.

The generated svg initially included a background color and three lines of text. This all works well if I use the image in a html page or open it directly in the browser.

Then I wanted to include a small pictogram (also an svg) based on the type of device.

If I call the svg directly the 2nd svg shows
If I use the svg in html the 2nd svg will not show (no error icon - just nothing) - but text and background work
If I enter a type with no 2nd svg file present, the browser will show an error icon included in the svg, if called from html also the error icon is missing.

What am I missing / messing up? Thanks in advance!

this is the relevant part of the php

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: image/svg+xml');

$sName = $_GET['name'];
$sIP = $_GET['ip'];
$sCheckFor = $_GET['suche'];
$sType = $_GET['typ'];

#[...] curl and such things

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="100">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" style="fill: ' . htmlspecialchars( $color, ENT_QUOTES ) . '"/>
    <text fill="' . $sTextColor . '" font-size="24" x="50%" y="25" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">' . str_replace("_", " ", $sName) . ' </text>
    <text fill="' . $sTextColor . '" font-size="12" x="50%" y="52" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">' . $sIP  . ' </text>
    <text fill="' . $sTextColor . '" font-size="18" x="50%" y="75" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">' . $response  . ' </text>';
    echo '<image x="10%" y="32%" width="50px" height="50px" href="./icons/' . $sType . '.svg" />';
    echo '</svg>';
```

and this the the html file:

```
<img src="./checkDevice.php?name=AmbiLamp&suche=AmbiLamp&ip=192.168.88.88&typ=lmp">
```

Comment: Sidenote: you almost certainly don't want to use echo here, but just a normal SVG file with `<?php ... ?>` as needed. If the overwhelming majority of your file is output, don't use echo.

Comment: I just left out all the "active" parts of the code since it is not required to reproduce the error.

Comment: Noted, but also: if all of that happen outside the SVG, rather than inline, worth considering that all of that can be done in a `<?php ... ?>` block before the SVG string data, so that you don't echo an entire document, with all the debugging hassle that comes with.

Comment: svgs loaded in an `<img>` element must be self contained so external resources won't be rendered and blocked. See ["Linked images inside SVG"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655736/linked-images-inside-svg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem when nesting SVG's within one another.

The issue you're having is being caused by the containing SVG `viewBox`. SVG's have a box size which defines how large to make the area the SVG elements can be displayed within.

The child SVG is inheriting the `viewBox` of the parent, which is most likely larger than you're needing, causing the SVG to display, but outside of the area intended.

A simple solution is to ensure both SVG's have the same `viewBox` sizing, but this sometimes isn't always easy to implement effectively.

Comment: Yes - that is the cause - now I have to face the fact that I did not yet fully understand the viewbox - my svg 1 is a lot larger than the icons (duh!) - I'll experiment. Thanks!

Comment: but then again I modified both php and 2nd svg with matching size viewports - now the 2nd svg is very small in the browser called svg but still nothing from html initiated... I'll dig deeper