# SVG in img tag not loading as image in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, svg

I am trying to load my svg file using an img tag but it is not working on firefox. Chrome shows the svg. I am trying to do it like this http://www.schepers.cc/svg/blendups/embedding.html.

Here is my code...

```html
<img src="http://ubuntu.digitalfront.ca/ghcorp/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/hillsdale.svg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
```

The svg doesn't show up at all in Firefox. How can I fix this?

Comment: What's in mymap.svg? What exactly is "not working"? Is the mime type correct? Can you see the image if you view the file directly? Is mymap.svg a single file with no external dependencies?

Comment: it has animation using css3

Comment: I have change my description.. thanks

Comment: I just wondering that i firefox the svg didn't show up

Comment: Didn't show at all (it does for me) or did show but didn't animate?

Comment: it didn't show in me in firefox.. but chrome does

Comment: The svg is displayed in Firefox Nightly 34 for me, but the path doesn't animate.

Comment: Same in Firefox 33: the SVG displays, but does not animate. Chrome renders it properly. The behavior in Opera 25 is the same as that in Firefox.

Comment: All the comments here are missing (part of) the point -- the .svg does not show at all when embedded in an "img" tag.  This is true of Firefox and Chrome -- IE does render the image, but not the animation.

Answer (score 19):

We have just encountered an issue where an SVG will not display in Firefox.
Preliminary testing suggests that the issue occurs if the ancestor of the img doesn't have a defined width... 
The img tag doesn't have an inline width or height definition either - so that may not be helping.
`<div><a><img src="image.svg"/></a></div>`
In this example - giving the div a width made the svg display.

PS Both the anchor tag and the img tag had css defined widths

Answer (score 6):

Beware! Showing an SVG on a webpage in an *img* element doesn't always work.

It works in many cases but NOT in some, such when the SVG file contains an embedded image (*image* element.)

According to [this source](https://www.sitepoint.com/add-svg-to-web-page/): "For security reasons, browsers will disable SVG scripts, linking and other types of interactivity when they’re added to your page with an img tag. In addition, IE9, Chrome and Safari won’t apply stylesheet rules to the SVG if they’re defined in a separate CSS file."

Comment: This answer helped me find the answer to my question 'why do the links in my svg not work when used in an img tag?' also have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352985/can-an-svg-included-in-html-with-an-img-tag-have-a-link-to-an-external-image-w and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604095/security-restrictions-when-linking-to-external-stylesheet-from-svg-when-embed

Answer (score 5):

I have a similar issue please refer to below screenshot. In firefox SVG was not loading. If I right click on image and open in new tab/window it was opening fine.

I have supplied `height="300"` and `width="150"` attribute to `img` tag and removed the width in `%age/auto` from `CSS`. This has fixed the issue for me.

I have also tried hard-coding the width in `px` instead of `%` in CSS only that worked as well.

So according to my understanding `SVG` requires a defined `height/width` in firefox to render properly either on image tag with height/width attributes or in CSS.

I hope it will help.

[image]

Comment: Adding an explicit width in the css worked for me!  Thanks

Comment: Awesome. Good to know that :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the mime type is set to: `image/svg+xml` as well.