# How do I include an svg image using the <svg> element?

Tags: html, image, svg, tags

I'm trying to include an svg image (from my local images folder) inside my page using the svg tag, but without success. Only a blank space appears instead of the image. It should be noted that I'm using a live server to display the page, and not just a local file (from what I know, svg tag only works on a server).

This is the content of the image file (it's called 'logo.svg', inside a folder called 'images'):

```
<svg width="240" height="39" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g fill-rule="nonzero" fill="none"><path d="M27.967.879C20.242.875 12.182 2.615 4.047 4.872c-1.033.208-2.041.884-2.574 1.72C.983 7.38.805 8.171.652 9c-.79 4.428-.694 8.776-.53 13.594.036 1.103.2 2.41.715 3.205.538.803 1.46 1.313 2.561 1.48a95.99 95.99 0 0 0 4.232.525l-.312 8.698c-.048.692.29 1.267.71 1.598.376.286.795.413 1.225.445.86.065 1.869-.303 2.37-1.257 2.195-4.224 3.572-6.089 6.317-8.895 7.158.176 13.407-.222 20.482-.745 2.501-.065 4.218-2.11 4.672-3.743 1.357-4.232 1.568-9.456 1.712-14.737.061-2.093-.665-4.148-1.95-5.234-1.222-.991-2.702-1.35-4.058-1.718C35.031 1.363 31.263.905 27.967.879zm10.29 3.31c1.358.369 2.555.724 3.31 1.337 1.26 1.339 1.218 2.23 1.2 3.675-.142 5.122-.388 10.093-1.544 13.86-.498 1.405-1.366 2.405-3.006 2.556-7.208.533-13.462.945-20.707.739a1.032 1.032 0 0 0-.763.302c-3.044 3.074-4.601 5.21-6.921 9.676-.054.102-.171.164-.315.175-.097-.005-.136-.08-.142-.148l.314-9.432c.019-.509-.401-.995-.907-1.05a95.48 95.48 0 0 1-5.06-.62c-.726-.111-.994-.31-1.193-.606-.346-.825-.338-1.335-.365-2.128-.162-4.775-.242-8.948.491-13.1.068-.614.298-1.242.542-1.767.404-.632 1.023-.725 1.644-.897 7.956-2.197 15.74-3.84 23.068-3.845 3.592.13 7.364.49 10.354 1.273zm-27.479 8.09c-1.096 1.313-.987 3.096-.14 4.29.442.625 1.132 1.128 1.972 1.242 1.091.09 1.783-.352 2.53-.86 1.353-1.176 1.49-3.228.461-4.71-.524-.755-1.362-1.208-2.218-1.24-1.172.012-1.968.535-2.605 1.277zm11.856-1.072c-1.092.035-1.975.791-2.514 1.607-.617.933-.977 2.101-.478 3.246.96 2.203 4.277 2.176 5.6-.063.61-1.032.454-2.205 0-3.056-.452-.85-1.136-1.543-2.131-1.702a2.494 2.494 0 0 0-.477-.032zm9.625.207c-.34-.008-.69.024-1.018.111-1.312.35-2.429 1.704-2.26 3.437.086.872.487 1.722 1.21 2.308.723.585 1.773.847 2.88.62 1.272-.26 2.06-1.285 2.323-2.275.263-.99.197-1.999-.414-2.817a3.47 3.47 0 0 0-2.72-1.384zm-18.965 1.623c.245.002.438.08.637.366.445.642.321 1.615-.128 2.005-.447.39-.726.424-.922.398-.196-.027-.395-.162-.573-.414-.34-.48-.44-1.256.007-1.81.238-.316.675-.513.98-.545zm9.483.223c.038.006.464.253.668.636.204.383.242.739.048 1.066-.577.976-1.804.712-1.99.287-.07-.162-.017-.813.32-1.32.335-.509.757-.7.954-.67zm10.564.748c.062.083.213.64.096 1.082-.118.442-.31.715-.78.811-.602.124-.94 0-1.193-.207-.254-.205-.425-.552-.462-.923-.09-.92.24-1.133.764-1.273.61-.15 1.3.112 1.575.51z" fill="#FF52C1"/><path d="M57.61 4.996c.016-.26.111-.494.287-.701a.875.875 0 0 1 .701-.31h6.826c.23 0 .467.096.712.287a.883.883 0 0 1 .368.724v10.893h11.421V4.996c0-.276.096-.513.287-.712.192-.2.44-.3.747-.3h6.734c.306 0 .574.077.804.23.23.154.345.399.345.736V37.1c0 .337-.1.59-.3.758-.198.169-.459.253-.78.253h-6.803c-.306 0-.555-.084-.747-.253-.191-.168-.287-.42-.287-.758V24.047H66.504V37.1c0 .322-.104.57-.31.747-.207.176-.487.264-.84.264h-6.756c-.643 0-.972-.299-.988-.896V4.996zm62.875 32.725c-.199.168-.41.275-.632.321a3.123 3.123 0 0 1-.631.07h-3.47c-.276 0-.514-.05-.713-.15-.2-.1-.368-.234-.506-.402a2.384 2.384 0 0 1-.344-.575 4.884 4.884 0 0 1-.23-.666l-.712-2.942c-.23.475-.563 1.015-1 1.62a8.495 8.495 0 0 1-1.666 1.7c-.674.53-1.479.974-2.413 1.334-.935.36-2.007.54-3.218.54-1.746 0-3.332-.337-4.757-1.011a10.904 10.904 0 0 1-3.642-2.758c-1.003-1.164-1.781-2.524-2.332-4.08-.552-1.554-.828-3.213-.828-4.974V10.695c0-.582.127-1.022.38-1.321.252-.299.654-.448 1.206-.448h5.308c.66 0 1.111.11 1.356.333.245.222.368.655.368 1.298v14.96c0 .66.15 1.284.448 1.874.299.59.693 1.11 1.184 1.562.49.452 1.045.809 1.666 1.069.62.26 1.252.39 1.896.39.551 0 1.122-.13 1.712-.39a6.361 6.361 0 0 0 1.631-1.046c.498-.436.908-.95 1.23-1.54.322-.59.482-1.214.482-1.872V10.626c0-.26.05-.52.15-.781.1-.26.249-.46.448-.598.199-.122.387-.206.563-.252.176-.046.38-.07.609-.07h5.194c.658 0 1.133.162 1.424.483.291.322.437.751.437 1.287v25.716c0 .29-.065.559-.195.804s-.31.437-.54.574l.137-.068zm26.681-3.172c-.414.414-.87.858-1.367 1.333-.498.475-1.046.92-1.643 1.333a9.3 9.3 0 0 1-1.93 1.023 6.097 6.097 0 0 1-2.23.402c-2.083 0-4.002-.39-5.757-1.172a13.777 13.777 0 0 1-4.527-3.206c-1.264-1.356-2.252-2.953-2.964-4.792-.713-1.838-1.069-3.814-1.069-5.929 0-2.13.356-4.11 1.069-5.94.712-1.83 1.7-3.424 2.964-4.78a13.635 13.635 0 0 1 4.527-3.194c1.755-.774 3.674-1.161 5.757-1.161.843 0 1.613.123 2.31.368a8.51 8.51 0 0 1 1.907.942c.575.383 1.103.816 1.586 1.298.482.483.938.954 1.367 1.414V1.985c0-.49.15-.903.448-1.24.299-.338.747-.506 1.345-.506h5.17c.2 0 .41.042.632.126.222.085.425.203.61.357.183.153.332.337.447.551.115.215.173.452.173.712v34.357c0 1.18-.62 1.77-1.862 1.77h-4.504c-.306 0-.544-.04-.712-.116a1.13 1.13 0 0 1-.426-.333 2.319 2.319 0 0 1-.31-.551 17.13 17.13 0 0 0-.344-.77l-.667-1.793zm-13.214-11.008a8.39 8.39 0 0 0 .471 2.839c.314.88.762 1.643 1.345 2.286a6.384 6.384 0 0 0 2.102 1.528c.82.376 1.728.563 2.724.563.98 0 1.903-.176 2.769-.528a7.058 7.058 0 0 0 2.263-1.46 7.256 7.256 0 0 0 1.552-2.194c.39-.843.609-1.747.655-2.712v-.322a7.26 7.26 0 0 0-.552-2.803 7.427 7.427 0 0 0-1.528-2.344 7.242 7.242 0 0 0-2.298-1.597 6.977 6.977 0 0 0-2.861-.586c-.996 0-1.904.195-2.724.586-.82.39-1.52.923-2.102 1.597a7.236 7.236 0 0 0-1.345 2.344 8.35 8.35 0 0 0-.47 2.803zm48.72 11.008c-.414.414-.87.858-1.368 1.333-.498.475-1.046.92-1.643 1.333a9.3 9.3 0 0 1-1.93 1.023 6.097 6.097 0 0 1-2.23.402c-2.083 0-4.002-.39-5.756-1.172a13.777 13.777 0 0 1-4.528-3.206c-1.263-1.356-2.252-2.953-2.964-4.792-.712-1.838-1.069-3.814-1.069-5.929 0-2.13.357-4.11 1.069-5.94s1.7-3.424 2.964-4.78a13.635 13.635 0 0 1 4.528-3.194c1.754-.774 3.673-1.161 5.756-1.161.843 0 1.613.123 2.31.368a8.51 8.51 0 0 1 1.907.942c.575.383 1.103.816 1.586 1.298.483.483.938.954 1.367 1.414V1.985c0-.49.15-.903.448-1.24.3-.338.747-.506 1.345-.506h5.17c.2 0 .41.042.632.126.223.085.426.203.61.357.183.153.333.337.448.551.114.215.172.452.172.712v34.357c0 1.18-.62 1.77-1.862 1.77h-4.504c-.306 0-.544-.04-.712-.116a1.13 1.13 0 0 1-.425-.333 2.319 2.319 0 0 1-.31-.551 17.13 17.13 0 0 0-.345-.77l-.667-1.793zm-13.215-11.008a8.39 8.39 0 0 0 .471 2.839c.315.88.763 1.643 1.345 2.286a6.384 6.384 0 0 0 2.103 1.528c.82.376 1.727.563 2.723.563.98 0 1.903-.176 2.769-.528a7.058 7.058 0 0 0 2.264-1.46 7.256 7.256 0 0 0 1.55-2.194c.391-.843.61-1.747.656-2.712v-.322a7.26 7.26 0 0 0-.552-2.803 7.427 7.427 0 0 0-1.528-2.344 7.242 7.242 0 0 0-2.298-1.597 6.977 6.977 0 0 0-2.861-.586c-.996 0-1.904.195-2.723.586-.82.39-1.521.923-2.103 1.597a7.236 7.236 0 0 0-1.345 2.344 8.35 8.35 0 0 0-.47 2.803zM197.61 2.008c0-.49.122-.903.367-1.24.246-.338.667-.506 1.264-.506h5.63c.154 0 .315.042.483.126a1.7 1.7 0 0 1 .471.357c.146.153.268.337.368.551.1.215.15.452.15.712v34.334c0 .582-.165 1.022-.495 1.321-.329.299-.754.448-1.275.448h-5.332c-.597 0-1.018-.15-1.264-.448-.245-.299-.367-.74-.367-1.321V2.008zm38.7 32.61a15.31 15.31 0 0 1-4.55 2.907 13.87 13.87 0 0 1-5.355 1.046c-2.1 0-4.083-.383-5.952-1.15a15.494 15.494 0 0 1-4.918-3.182 15.273 15.273 0 0 1-3.355-4.792c-.828-1.838-1.241-3.837-1.241-5.998 0-1.348.164-2.654.494-3.918a15.45 15.45 0 0 1 1.402-3.55 15.055 15.055 0 0 1 2.206-3.045 13.957 13.957 0 0 1 2.907-2.379 14.327 14.327 0 0 1 3.493-1.54 14.084 14.084 0 0 1 3.975-.551c1.272 0 2.505.169 3.7.506 1.195.337 2.318.812 3.367 1.424 1.05.613 2.01 1.349 2.884 2.207a14.896 14.896 0 0 1 2.252 2.815 13.58 13.58 0 0 1 1.46 3.263c.344 1.157.517 2.348.517 3.573 0 .797-.012 1.448-.035 1.954-.023.505-.142.908-.356 1.206-.215.3-.57.506-1.069.62-.498.116-1.23.173-2.194.173h-16.546c.153.98.463 1.8.93 2.46a5.842 5.842 0 0 0 1.62 1.573c.613.391 1.264.67 1.954.84a8.24 8.24 0 0 0 1.953.252c.552 0 1.118-.058 1.7-.172a12.179 12.179 0 0 0 1.69-.46 9.557 9.557 0 0 0 1.493-.667c.452-.252.816-.517 1.092-.792.245-.2.456-.349.632-.449.176-.1.364-.149.563-.149.2 0 .402.07.61.207a4.8 4.8 0 0 1 .7.597l2.436 2.758c.168.2.276.38.322.54.046.161.069.326.069.494 0 .307-.085.571-.253.793a2.89 2.89 0 0 1-.598.586zm-11.054-19.143c-.598 0-1.176.119-1.735.356a6.547 6.547 0 0 0-1.575.954c-.49.398-.93.85-1.321 1.356a8.315 8.315 0 0 0-.954 1.54h11.743a13.536 13.536 0 0 0-1.045-1.655 7.081 7.081 0 0 0-1.287-1.333 5.558 5.558 0 0 0-1.655-.896c-.62-.215-1.344-.322-2.171-.322z" fill="#00252E"/></g></svg>
```

And this is the HTML code that I tried and didn't work:

```
        <svg class="footer__logo">
          <use xlink:href="images/logo.svg"></use>
        </svg>
```

Can you please tell me how to do it right?

Comment: use cannot reference a complete file in most browsers. It's a proposal in SVG 2 but I don't think it's implemented anywhere yet. Use image for a complete file or use with a fragment identifier.

Answer (score 0):

SVG should work on a local server, it is no different from an HTML file.

If you double click the SVG file on your file system, a Browser opens, because by default `.svg` is associated as a file to be opened by the default Browser.

SVG **content** has CORS security restrictions to prevent content being opened from another file location; so you can't easily load external content

Only way around that is with JavaScript Code, see:
[SVG entire transparent in img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61751668/svg-entire-transparent-in-img-tag)

In your case it is probably all about loading the SVG right:

```
<img class="footer__logo" src="images/logo.svg">
```

`<use>` notation is when you have **multiple** symbols/icons in **one** SVG file,
see: https://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/

Side note: You can save over 50% in SVG file size with: https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/

Comment: Well <use> works only with fragments and the OP is missing a fragment identifier. Or alternatively maybe no fragment identifier but then you want <image> or <object> or <iframe>

Comment: We'll see what his answer is... for now I say he probably needs ``<img src=`` as he wants to display his logo.svg in a footer

Comment: The thing is, I want to change the image's color in css (using the 'fill' property). Will I be able to do that if I use <img>, <object> or <ifame> instead of the <use> tag? If so, what should the html code be like? Or alternatively - can I add a fragment identifier into the image's svg file? If so how?