# chm/pdf alternative based on html5+js and opened with the user's web browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chm

I've read tons of similar questions in the Web, but found nothing that is acceptable for me. So, I'm looking for an html5+css+js solution for an offline use that looks similar to chm/pdf. My requirements:
1. All resources are stored in one single file, and I want to edit the source code directly and easily.
2. It's javascript-enabled and opened by the browser.
3. I **don't** need a built-in index/search functionality.
I tried to write something on my own, but it can't get rid of a serious memory leak...

Comment: I thought JS was garbage collected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa563064) would be an alternative. Here are some examples:

- [Key Concepts of MHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/ms988645)
- [MIME Hierarchies of body parts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa563064)

Another alternative would be SVG with data-uris to embed images and markup. Here are some examples:

- [Embed data-uris in SVG](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets/Data_URIs)
- [Does SVG support embedding of bitmap images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249664/does-svg-support-embedding-of-bitmap-images)

Comment: MHTML/SVG aren't the same as HTML5+JS... Anyway, never mind, my original question wasn't a good idea...