# How to import an image/raster in svg-edit using the embedded API

Tags: base64, svg-edit

I determined using the core api that the method "svgCanvas.importImage(url) can import base64 encoded images.

But the embedded API does not expose this method which is private.  It also seems i can not use any of the methods that method uses (svgFromgJson, etc).

Does anyone have advice on how I can load a base 64 string representing an image when the embedded svg-edit starts up?  I am thinking to just wrap that string inside an < image> tag in a mock svg file and import that way..

[Does SVG support embedding of bitmap images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249664/does-svg-support-embedding-of-bitmap-images)

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the existing code, based on the answer in my original question I modified their sample import, and it works just wonderfully.

1. Include the embedapi.js in your page
2. Define an Iframe to show svg-edit
3. Call the following code function in the iframe's onload event

   ```
   // call onLoad for the iframe
    var frame = document.getElementById('svgedit');
       svgCanvas = new embedded_svg_edit(frame);

    // Hide main button, as we will be controlling new/load/save etc from the host document
    var doc;
    doc = frame.contentDocument;
    if (!doc)
    {
      doc = frame.contentWindow.document;
    }

     var mainButton = doc.getElementById('main_button');
     mainButton.style.display = 'none';            
     var embeddedImage='<image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,..OMITTED FOR BREVITY.." id="svg_2" height="128" width="128" y="0" x="0"/>';

     var svgDef = '<svg width="128" height="128" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><title>Layer 1</title>' + embeddedImage +  '</g></svg>';
      svgCanvas.setSvgString(svgDef);

   }
   ```

Comment: Hi Eddie. Could you post a working zip file of your example. I am very interested. Thanks.

Comment: The working code is embedded in a SVG editing plugin I wrote for confluence, https://bitbucket.org/eddiewebb/confluence-scribbles/src