# How can I display an image inside SVG circle in html5?

Tags: html, image, svg

Is there a way to  display an image inside **SVG Circle** ?

I tried adding the image inside Svg element but the image does not appear in the circle.

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40"stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
<img src="starkeen_ane.jpg"/>
 </svg>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Inside svg you should use `<image>` not `<img>`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249664/does-svg-support-embedding-of-bitmap-images

Comment: Also, if you are expecting the image to display round, like filling the circle, then you will have to use  `<clipPath>`. Google it for examples.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here is an example elaborating on Havenard's comment above:

```html
<svg width="500" height="250">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="circleView">
            <circle cx="250" cy="125" r="125" fill="#FFFFFF" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <image 
      width="500" 
      height="250" 
      xlink:href="https://www.amrita.edu/sites/default/files/news-images/new/news-events/images/l-nov/grass.jpg" 
      clip-path="url(#circleView)"
    />
 </svg>
```

You don't actually draw a `<circle>` element with an image inside - instead, define a circular clip path, and set it as the 'clip-path' attribute on the `<image>` tag.

Comment: Don't use a mask as a clipPath. Use a clipPath, that's why a clipPath exists. A mask is a raster operation, uses lots of memory and is slow.

Comment: D'oh. Good point, Robert.  Updated example.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking.

Comment: Very nice. FYI, it seems that the fill attr does nothing here.

Answer (score 1):

It is maybe not the best way to do it. but it works very good. The thing you can do it place it to a relative position and edit top and left properties so you image is in the center of your svg image. Also important is to place it outside your `svg`-tag.

```css
img {
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
  left: -70px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40"stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
 </svg>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxCmj.png"/>
```

Comment: And then you have a white space padded under the `<svg>` with the same height of the image. Thats how bad it is to abuse `position: relative` for ordinary things.