# Text on a Circle Path around an SVG Image

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm attempting to have animated text moving on a circular path around an image. I have the circular text, but I can't get the image on the inside.

Here is the code I'm using:

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="circle">
    <svg 
      version="1.1" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
      x="0px" 
      y="0px" 
      width="200px" 
      height="200px" 
      viewBox="0 0 400 400" 
      enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" 
      xml:space="preserve"
    >
      <defs>
        <path id="circlePath" d=" M 200, 200 m -60, 0 a 60,60 0 0,1 120,0 a 60,60 0 0,1 -120,0 "/>
      </defs>
      <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="75" fill="none"/>
      <g>
        <use xlink:href="#circlePath" fill="none"/>
        <text fill="#ffb605">
          <textPath xlink:href="#circlePath">Flip the Bird • Flip the Bird • </textPath>
        </text>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the full code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/keqcyx57/) I created.

The svg I'm trying to place in the middle is this: https://svgshare.com/i/Z4d.svg

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't seem to have specified a central image to display. What is it?

Comment: The central image I want to display is: https://svgshare.com/i/Z4d.svg

Comment: Yes, but this imageis not specified in your SVG code above hence this is why the central image will not appear

Comment: [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897108/how-can-i-display-an-image-inside-svg-circle-in-html5) may help you

Comment: the other svg in nothing but an image. Use the image inside your circle path svg. You will need to change the size of the image (width height) and the position (x,y). you can clip the image with the circle or you can use the image as a pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496734/add-a-background-image-png-to-a-svg-circle-shape But since your image is transparent you can put it behind the text group. Also in your code you have a fully transparent circle. Do you need it or is it there by error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this with the `image` tag:

```html
<image
  x="165" 
  y="150"
  width="88" 
  height="100"
  xlink:href="PATH_TO_YOUR_IMAGE.EXTENSION"
/>
```

or (like in your linked svg)

```html
<image
  ...
  xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,YOUR_LOOOOONG_IMAGE_DATA"
/>
```

To move only the text and not the whole image (inkl. the inner bird image) you should define the rotation only for the text:

```css
#circle svg text {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-name: rotate;
  ...
}
```

**Working example:** (*i removed the circle because it wasn't used*)

Unfortunately your linked svg doesn't work here because it's on another domain (but worked locally in my test file). And the inline image data from that svg doesn't fit in the stack snippet (also worked locally in my test file). Therefor i used a simple `rect` for demonstration.

```css
#circle {
  position: relative;
}

#circle text {
  margin: 0 calc(.14em * -1) 0 0;
  font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", "serif";
  font-size: .83em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.4;
  letter-spacing: .14em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  background: linear-gradient(-67deg, #000000 0%, #988d87 28%, #797371 52%, #5e5855 82%, #000000 100%);
  background-size: 100% auto;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  letter-spacing: .32em;
}

#circle svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#circle svg text {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
  -moz-animation-name: rotate;
  -ms-animation-name: rotate;
  -o-animation-name: rotate;
  animation-name: rotate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 10s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 10s;
  -o-animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -o-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@media screen and ( max-width: 979px) {
  #circle svg {
    height: 360px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="circle">
  <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
      <defs>
        <path id="circlePath" d=" M 200, 200 m -60, 0 a 60,60 0 0,1 120,0 a 60,60 0 0,1 -120,0 "/>
      </defs>
      <g>
        <use xlink:href="#circlePath" fill="none"/>
        <rect
          x="160" 
          y="160"
          width="80" 
          height="80"
          fill="#FCDB8D"
        />
        <text fill="#ffb605">
          <textPath xlink:href="#circlePath">Flip the Bird • Flip the Bird • </textPath>
        </text>
      </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Side note: With SVG 2 (implementation [in progress](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5760616295825408)) you can define whether the text is rendered inward or outward with the new [`side`](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#text-TextPathElementSideAttribute) attribute on the [`textPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath) element.