# How to show a PNG image inside a <svg> tag?

Tags: html, image, svg, responsive-design

I have a `<svg>` tag with `viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"` where I paint a polygon which draws a triangle over some parts of the 1000x1000 box. This SVG then gets scaled to `width="100"`.

I want to add a PNG image, for example https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg, in the background of the SVG, behind the triangle, which will also get scaled in the same way.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" width="100">
<polygon points="100 100, 900 100, 900 900" />
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you given correct co-ordinates to svg image?

Comment: @rattlesnake This Might Help you :   https://stackoverflow.com/a/30897481/13858444

Comment: Alternative Support : https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/html/display+svg+image+in+html

Answer (score 2):

It's simply `<image>`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" width="100">
<image x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="1000" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" />
<polygon points="100 100, 900 100, 900 900" />
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```