# How to render an image inside a svg tag properly in html?

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to display image inside  tag with other contents. All things are rendering properly but the image is not being rendering in the UI.

Here is my source code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Portal</title>
    <style>
        .display-top-right {
            position: fixed;
            left: 40%;
            top: 10%;
            width: 25vw;
            height: 28vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="p-1 my-container">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 30px;">
            <div id="profile-box">
                <svg class="display-top-right">
                    <defs>
                        <filter id="f4" x="0" y="0" width="200%" height="200%">
                            <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceGraphic" dx="20" dy="20" />
                            <feColorMatrix result="matrixOut" in="offOut" type="matrix"
                                           values="0.2 0 0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" />
                            <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="matrixOut" stdDeviation="10" />
                            <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
                        </filter>
                    </defs>
                    <rect width="20vw" height="25vh" stroke="green" stroke-width="1"
                          fill="white" filter="url(#f4)" />
                    <text x="15" y="35" font-size="10pt" style="fill:black;">
                        Test Company Solutions       <a xlink:href="">  Sign Out</a>
                    </text>
                    <img height="50" width="50" x="0" y="50" src="~/Content/Images/Generator.png"></img>
                    <text x="100" y="100" style="fill:black;" font-size="10pt">
                        <tspan x="100" y="105">Test Name</tspan>
                        <tspan x="100" y="125">TestName@gmail.com</tspan>
                    </text>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you please help me to identity what is going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try `<image height="50" width="50" x="0" y="50" xlink:href="whatever"> </image>`  You may also try `href` instead of xlink:href

Comment: SVG doesn't use `<img src="...`, it uses `<image href="...`: [How can I display an image inside SVG circle in html5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897108/how-can-i-display-an-image-inside-svg-circle-in-html5)

Comment: @enxaneta that worked for me. Thank you.