# How to Incorporate an SVG inside an SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to add an SVG inside an SVG so that I can manipulate the fill colors of both of them.

For example, if I have an SVG of Square with path fill of Red, and I want to add SVG of a circle with color blue I can do it by writing 2 SVG with position absolute, but I want the circle SVG inside the Square SVG multiplying itself to the fill the Square SVG space limiting itself to Square SVG's area only.

Like this.
[image]

Which I did achieve by adding an image as a pattern inside that Square SVG. Like:

```html
 <svg class="blowse" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" viewBox="0 0 46.000000 66.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" >
        <g transform="translate(0.000000,66.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#000000" stroke="none">
           <pattern id="blowse_pattern_img" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%">
               <image id="blowse_img" href="https://harryatwork.com/vinay/images/club.png" x="0" y="0" width="50px" height="50px"></image>
           </pattern>
           <path style="fill:red;" class="path_blowse" d="M343 619 c-6 -6 -26 -12 -44 -13 -127 -11 -279 -102 -266 -158 7 -29 67 -196 94 -263 11 -27 26 -69 32 -92 7 -24 20 -47 30 -53 17 -9 19 -4 23 63 3 55 11 88 36 138 28 58 43 75 110 125 l79 59 -18 29 c-16 26 -26 60 -45 154 -5 24 -14 28 -31 11z" />
           <path style="fill:url(#blowse_pattern_img)" class="path_blowse_img" d="M343 619 c-6 -6 -26 -12 -44 -13 -127 -11 -279 -102 -266 -158 7 -29 67 -196 94 -263 11 -27 26 -69 32 -92 7 -24 20 -47 30 -53 17 -9 19 -4 23 63 3 55 11 88 36 138 28 58 43 75 110 125 l79 59 -18 29 c-16 26 -26 60 -45 154 -5 24 -14 28 -31 11z" />
       </g>
    </svg>
```

However, using JQuery I can manipulate the Parent SVG's fill but I cannot do anything about the image that I did just added.

So to Manipulate the color of the child, I need it to be an SVG instead of an Image.

So, I need to add another path of that shape along with the parent path. like :

```html
 <svg class="blowse" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" viewBox="0 0 46.000000 66.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" >
        <g transform="translate(0.000000,66.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#000000" stroke="none">
           <path class="path_blowse" d="M343 619 c-6 -6 -26 -12 -44 -13 -127 -11 -279 -102 -266 -158 7 -29 67 -196 94 -263 11 -27 26 -69 32 -92 7 -24 20 -47 30 -53 17 -9 19 -4 23 63 3 55 11 88 36 138 28 58 43 75 110 125 l79 59 -18 29 c-16 26 -26 60 -45 154 -5 24 -14 28 -31 11z" />
          <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M5656 11870 c-498 -45 -890 -217 -1275 -559 -403 -360 -677 -1053 -698 -1766 -11 -366 36 -549 248 -980 161 -328 202 -435 165 -435 -27 0 -153 43 -311 105 -327 130 -593 184 -1015 204 -340 17 -465 -6 -714 -131 -207 -104 -385 -237 -592 -443 -242 -241 -393 -448 -524 -720 -169 -349 -207 -506 -217 -886 -9 -328 17 -544 87 -744 38 -108 183 -418 247 -530 358 -624 949 -1041 1653 -1165 159 -28 479 -38 642 -20 531 58 1102 312 1543 684 156 132 362 348 474 498 24 32 144 207 267 390 149 221 230 333 242 333 26 0 33 -60 26 -250 -12 -385 -35 -617 -85 -870 -143 -725 -468 -1336 -988 -1855 -181 -181 -280 -265 -440 -371 -268 -178 -520 -276 -1206 -468 -471 -132 -622 -190 -709 -274 -43 -41 -75 -112 -58 -129 14 -14 479 -27 1312 -39 1056 -14 5327 -7 5545 10 308 23 350 44 296 149 -45 86 -120 127 -316 172 -414 94 -887 235 -1170 348 -376 151 -662 347 -970 663 -436 449 -744 1015 -879 1619 -52 236 -112 621 -146 938 -20 197 -27 422 -12 422 13 0 136 -168 282 -386 263 -392 453 -616 720 -848 515 -447 1168 -722 1765 -743 363 -12 718 68 1070 242 267 132 454 266 657 472 204 206 327 383 473 678 109 219 146 325 177 497 21 113 23 154 23 488 0 306 -3 383 -18 479 -33 205 -86 358 -212 613 -128 259 -262 444 -461 638 -185 180 -312 270 -539 380 -313 153 -572 207 -933 197 -314 -9 -487 -53 -857 -217 -210 -93 -349 -150 -365 -150 -32 0 17 130 174 463 169 356 219 499 251 712 47 316 -20 800 -167 1195 -119 320 -280 574 -499 785 -361 349 -729 524 -1240 591 -145 18 -575 27 -723 14z"/> 
       </g>
    </svg>
```

Which did nothing.

Hope I was clear in explaining my query.

[Working FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/harish3693/geuwj6s5/8/)

I need an SVG instead of an image there.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `defs`, `symbol` and `use` helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34225008/402322

Comment: Side note: I would advise you to use `currentColor` instead of an actual color in your SVG if you need it to change. It's easier as you just need to change the `color: green;` in css. No need to loop over multiple SVG if they have the same class for a specific color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed the inner SVG directly:

```html
<svg class="blowse" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" viewBox="0 0 46.000000 66.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" >
  <g transform="translate(0.000000,66.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#000000" stroke="none">
    <pattern id="blowse_pattern_img" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
        <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="210" fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-width="8"/>
      </svg>
    </pattern>
    <path style="fill:red;" class="path_blowse" d="M343 619 c-6 -6 -26 -12 -44 -13 -127 -11 -279 -102 -266 -158 7 -29 67 -196 94 -263 11 -27 26 -69 32 -92 7 -24 20 -47 30 -53 17 -9 19 -4 23 63 3 55 11 88 36 138 28 58 43 75 110 125 l79 59 -18 29 c-16 26 -26 60 -45 154 -5 24 -14 28 -31 11z" />
    <path style="fill:url(#blowse_pattern_img)" class="path_blowse_img" d="M343 619 c-6 -6 -26 -12 -44 -13 -127 -11 -279 -102 -266 -158 7 -29 67 -196 94 -263 11 -27 26 -69 32 -92 7 -24 20 -47 30 -53 17 -9 19 -4 23 63 3 55 11 88 36 138 28 58 43 75 110 125 l79 59 -18 29 c-16 26 -26 60 -45 154 -5 24 -14 28 -31 11z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

In this way, it can be controlled as a separate item with its own context.

Answer (score 2):

The club path is far away outside the svg canvas. Besides is much bigger than the path you need to fill with the pattern.

In order to see the club I'm putting it in a symbol with a viewBox and use the symbol with the position (x,y) and the size (width, height) I want. (the red club in the next example)

I also can use the symbol to build a pattern and use the pattern to fill the shape.

```html
<svg class="blowse" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" viewBox="0 0 46.000000 66.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

  <g transform="translate(0.000000,66.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#000000" stroke="none">
    <path fill="url(#blowse_pattern_img)" class="path_blowse" d="M343 619 c-6 -6 -26 -12 -44 -13 -127 -11 -279 -102 -266 -158 7 -29 67 -196 94 -263 11 -27 26 -69 32 -92 7 -24 20 -47 30 -53 17 -9 19 -4 23 63 3 55 11 88 36 138 28 58 43 75 110 125 l79 59 -18 29 c-16 26 -26 60 -45 154 -5 24 -14 28 -31 11z" />
    <use href="#club" x="100" y="400" width="30" height="30" fill="red" />

  </g>


<defs>
  <pattern id="blowse_pattern_img" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="30" height="30">
    <use href="#club" width="20" height="20" fill="gold" />
  </pattern>
  <symbol viewBox="720 1440 10530 10530" id="club">
    <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M5656 11870 c-498 -45 -890 -217 -1275 -559 -403 -360 -677 -1053 -698 -1766 -11 -366 36 -549 248 -980 161 -328 202 -435 165 -435 -27 0 -153 43 -311 105 -327 130 -593 184 -1015 204 -340 17 -465 -6 -714 -131 -207 -104 -385 -237 -592 -443 -242 -241 -393 -448 -524 -720 -169 -349 -207 -506 -217 -886 -9 -328 17 -544 87 -744 38 -108 183 -418 247 -530 358 -624 949 -1041 1653 -1165 159 -28 479 -38 642 -20 531 58 1102 312 1543 684 156 132 362 348 474 498 24 32 144 207 267 390 149 221 230 333 242 333 26 0 33 -60 26 -250 -12 -385 -35 -617 -85 -870 -143 -725 -468 -1336 -988 -1855 -181 -181 -280 -265 -440 -371 -268 -178 -520 -276 -1206 -468 -471 -132 -622 -190 -709 -274 -43 -41 -75 -112 -58 -129 14 -14 479 -27 1312 -39 1056 -14 5327 -7 5545 10 308 23 350 44 296 149 -45 86 -120 127 -316 172 -414 94 -887 235 -1170 348 -376 151 -662 347 -970 663 -436 449 -744 1015 -879 1619 -52 236 -112 621 -146 938 -20 197 -27 422 -12 422 13 0 136 -168 282 -386 263 -392 453 -616 720 -848 515 -447 1168 -722 1765 -743 363 -12 718 68 1070 242 267 132 454 266 657 472 204 206 327 383 473 678 109 219 146 325 177 497 21 113 23 154 23 488 0 306 -3 383 -18 479 -33 205 -86 358 -212 613 -128 259 -262 444 -461 638 -185 180 -312 270 -539 380 -313 153 -572 207 -933 197 -314 -9 -487 -53 -857 -217 -210 -93 -349 -150 -365 -150 -32 0 17 130 174 463 169 356 219 499 251 712 47 316 -20 800 -167 1195 -119 320 -280 574 -499 785 -361 349 -729 524 -1240 591 -145 18 -575 27 -723 14z" />
  </symbol>
</defs>
</svg>
```