# Re-scale svg element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, draw

I have different `rect` elements that are drawn inside an `svg` layer which is overlapped over a `png` image.

In another view I can see the elements drawn but the image below is bigger and it hasn't same scale factor, if I divide the width for height for both the images, the results aren't the same.

How can I re-scale an svg element inside an image with two different scale factors?

These images could explain what I mean to do

Image with rect drawn:
[image: image with rect drawn]

Image that I should re-scale:
[image: image that I should re-scale]

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249664/does-svg-support-embedding-of-bitmap-images. maybe embedding image file will help to deal with this kind of stuff.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are the rects being used only as event catchers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem with a simple function.
Ours unknowns are the rect's coordinates that we want to re-scale and its size, so if we denote with *oldRectX* and *oldRectY*, *newRectX* and *newRectY* rispectively as the old and the new rect's coordinates and with *oldSVGWidth* and *oldSVGHeight*, *newSVGWidth* and *newSVGHeight* rispectively as the old and the new SVG's dimensions that contains the rects, applying this ratio we can calculate the new positionament and the new size:

```
oldRectX : oldSVGWidth = newRectX : newSVGWidth
```

So I can calculate newRectX:

```
newRectX = (oldRectX * newSVGWidth)/oldSVGWith
```

The same reasoning it's apply for calculate newRectY with the difference that I have to replace the width with the height and X with Y:

```
newRectY = (oldRectY * newSVGHeight)/oldSVGHeight
```

Finally the new sizes:

```
newRectWidth = oldRectWidth * (newSVGWidth/oldSVGWidth)
newRectHeight = oldRectWidth * (newSVGHeight/oldSVGHeight)
```