# It is possible to put an image into a SVG image?

Tags: html, css, image, svg

it is possible to put an image into a SVG image ? Like "background-image" of CSS.

Thanks,

ARK.

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: Are you looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does SVG support embedding of bitmap images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249664/does-svg-support-embedding-of-bitmap-images)