# Can I plot svg over jpg and output the file as svg with python

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg, png, jpeg

I'm trying to plot icons (small 48x48 svg image) over another image (jpg file, quite big) at different locations. What I would want is to plot the svg icons on the jpg image in a way that my output file is a svg with the vectorized icons but not the map which is a raster element.
Is it even possible (any workaround that would lead to the solution is welcome), and if so, can I do it with python ?

Comment: how do you do it? Maybe you should put `svg` directly in `HTML` and use `css` to locate it in expected place

Comment: Great idea ! If there's not other simpler solution i'll definitely try this out

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/6250418/2836621